# Prometheus cAdvisor docker monitoring

Tags: docker, monitoring, prometheus, cadvisor

I've setup a docker monitoring stack using Prometheus, Grafana and cAdvisor. While using this query to get running containers:

```
count_scalar(container_last_seen{name=~container1|container2})
```

It picks up the containers allright, as soon as i launch a new container it is picked up right away. The problem is when a container is stopped or removed it does not pick it up, it still shows it as a running container.

From the cAdvisor/metrics endpoint it is removed as soon as the container stops.

Is there something wrong with the query?

(this is what i used for the stack: https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be related to the [amount of time cAdvisor stores the data in memory](https://github.com/vegasbrianc/prometheus/issues/3).

While cAdvisor keeps the data in memory, you still have a valid date in `container_last_seen` metric. So the `count_scalar` instruction still 'sees' the container as it has a valid value.

In my test setup, cAdvisor keeps the data during 5 minutes. After this duration, I get the right information out of your formula because the `container_last_seen` metric has disappeared.

You can change this cAdvisor configuration with the [`--storage_duration`](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/runtime_options.md#local-storage-duration) flag.

```
--storage_duration=2m0s: How long to store data.
```

As an **alternative** if you wan't quick alerting, you could also consider running a query that would compare last seen date with current date:

```
count_scalar(time()-container_last_seen{name=~"container1|container2"}<=60)
```